# sort filenames by their time created on linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, glob

Is it possible to get the file name of the most recently created one in a given directory?
I wanted to use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) but I realized glob can't sort anything.
Can I sort the files and then use glob to get the names? How do I do the first step of sorting files by time created?

By the way, I'm working on a centos 7 machine.

Comment: @dtanabe No, that windows one doesn't work. I need an answer for linux machines.

Comment: Although "Windows" is in the title, the examples in the linked post generally seem operating system-agnostic.